# mciSendString with Visual C++ - Parameters?

Tags: winapi, visual-studio-2008, c++-cli

I am not a native C++ programmer, so I need some help with the following:

I got this code working:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")

LPCWSTR openCDCommand = L"set cdaudio door open";
//comes from Windows.h, needs winmm.lib see header includes
int errCode = mciSendString(openCDCommand, 0, 0, 0);
```

#### Questions:

- Do I need to work with LPCWSTR? Why didn't I find a System::String example?
- How should I handle 'string concatination'? I cant simply do L"foo"+L"baar"?
- Am I on the totally wrong way to play sounds with mciSendString? (actually I really want to use MCI Command and MCI sendString as i did in other projects before)
- Is there another way to include the external function mciSendString so it can handle handles?

Comment: current project code can be found here: 
https://github.com/honky/SoftwareProjektTUBAF2013/blob/master/SoundBoard/SoundBoard/Player.cpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The signature of mciSendString is

   `MCIERROR mciSendString(
     LPCTSTR lpszCommand,
     LPTSTR lpszReturnString,
     UINT cchReturn,
     HANDLE hwndCallback);`

So, regarding the first 2 parameters, in unicode it will be a wchar pointer and in multibyte it will be a char pointer. It's the signature. You cannot change that and you shouldn't worry about that.

1. `std::wstring someString( L"Foo" );`
   `someString.append( L"bar ");`
2. I would play sound with core audio API, waveOut or maybe DirectSound. But, not with the `mciSendString()`.
3. I'm afraid I don't understand this one.. can you explain it better?

Answer (score 1):

This now works for me - took some time, but maybe in future this will help others:

```
#include "vcclr.h" // compile with /clr(!)
int Player::mciSendStringHandle(String ^ givenHandle)
{
    pin_ptr<const wchar_t> wch = PtrToStringChars(givenHandle);
    return mciSendString(wch, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's the right way to get a Unicode C-style string from a .NET-style `System::String`.